# VBA to hide rows between selected icon and a named cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a rookie at VBA and I've been trying for days to get this one to work. I have multiple rows of items that make up a total assembly. The top row of the range is the assembly name and the bottom row is the subtotals of the columns that make up all items. I've made an icon, and inserted it into the header row, which I've assigned a macro that I'd like to hide the rows between the selected icon and the "Subtotal" row. I'd also like it to unhide in case I want to review the items. This happens dozens of times on the sheet and I continually add assemblies so it can't be a static range. Also the number of items (or rows) between the headers and subtotal rows varies. See attached pic.[Assembly Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD2mq.jpg)

Below is what I've written so far and it works great for the first time the instance happens on the sheet. For assemblies below this one it hides more than I want. Thanks for your help in advance!!

```
Sub HideAssembly()
Dim F1 As Range, F2 As Range
Set F1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
Set F2 = Columns("C").Find(what:="ASSEMBLY SUB TOTAL", LookIn:=xlValues, 
lookat:=xlWhole)
If Rows(F1.Row + 1 & ":" & F2.Row - 1).Hidden = False Then
   Rows(F1.Row + 1 & ":" & F2.Row - 1).Hidden = True
Else
   Rows(F1.Row + 1 & ":" & F2.Row - 1).Hidden = False
End If
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Application.Caller).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation 180
End With
SendKeys ("{ESC}")

End Sub
```

Comment: Before looking at code, are you familiar with Data, Subtotal and Data, Group? Because it looks like you're trying to recreate functionality that's already built in to Excel?

Comment: Step through the code and see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea - in stead of:

```
If Rows(F1.Row + 1 & ":" & F2.Row - 1).Hidden = False Then
   Rows(F1.Row + 1 & ":" & F2.Row - 1).Hidden = True
Else
   Rows(F1.Row + 1 & ":" & F2.Row - 1).Hidden = False
End If
```

write:

```
Rows(F1.Row + 1 & ":" & F2.Row - 1).Hidden= Not Rows(F1.Row + 1 & ":" & F2.Row - 1).Hidden
```

It does the same.